# JavaScript to launch Spell Check when Ribbon is hidden

Tags: 2010, development, ribbon

The SharePoint 2010 Ribbon has a Spelling button that spell checks the page. We are using CSS to hide the ribbon for certain lists that have custom Edit and Display forms. Is there a JavaScript function for this spell check feature I can just call from a link, so I don't have to display the ribbon?

Comment: I believe it all originates from sp.ui.spellcheck.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once achieved it this way:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function doSpellCheck() {
          SpellCheckEntirePage(‘/_vti_bin/SpellCheck.asmx’,‘/_layouts/SpellChecker.aspx’);
     }
</script>
```

And

```
<a class="ms-toolbar" href="javascript:doSpellCheck()">Spelling…</a>
```

Following [this article](https://clintoncherry.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/adding-spell-checker-to-custom-sharepoint-pages/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar answer on this blog, but I think the answer you found is cleaner. http://www.bigscholar.com/2013/01/03/spell-checking-textbox-user-controls-with-sp2010/

Comment: That's basically the same thing :)

Comment: Oh, I see, you wrapped SpellCheckEntirePage() in doSpellCheck().